# mysql query where I get the count of rows value equal to a row of same table

Tags: mysql

Can I have a mysql query where I get the count of rows, value equal to a row of same table.

Please check my below query and Can I optimize it. It's taking very long time to load

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN 
        table1.issue_type = 'email' 
    THEN 
        (SELECT Count(tabl1a.id) FROM table1 AS table1a WHERE table1a.email = table1.email)
    ELSE 
        (SELECT Count(table1a.id) FROM table1 AS table1a WHERE table1a.phone_day = table1.phone_day) 
    END 
    AS emails
    FROM table1
```

Advice me please

Comment: This is your whole query? You don't select any other columns? This query would only get you a lot of numbers, many of them duplicates. (E.g. with two emails = 'john', two emails = 'jane' and three non-emails on phone_day 100, you'd get something like 2,3,3,2,3,2,2.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual remedy for such correlated subqueries in a select clause is to refactor by instead joining to a subquery which performs the aggregation.  In this case, there are actually two different aggregations which you are doing, so we can left join to two subqueries to perform the aggregations.

```
SELECT
    t1.issue_type,
    COALESCE(t2.email_cnt, t3.phone_cnt) AS emails
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS email_cnt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY email
) t2
    ON t1.email = t2.email AND
       t1.issue_type = 'email'
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT phone_day, COUNT(*) AS phone_cnt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY phone_day
) t3
    ON t1.phone_day = t3.phone_day AND
       t1.issue_type <> 'email'
```

The trick here to add a condition to the join criteria checking whether or not the issue type is email.  This guarantees that each record in your table will join to one and only one subquery.  We use `COALESCE` to choose the non NULL count, coming from either the email or phone day aggregation.

Comment: @Mjh: And yours obviously :-) Tim is just advising to move the subqueries from SELECT to FROM. No big deal. A good DBMS wouldn't make a difference between the two, but MySQL is known for not having a great optimizer. The issue_type is compared here in the join, but could just as well get compared in the SELECT clause, which again shouldn't make a difference, but it's still worth a try. This query is not rocket science, and Tim may have spent some ten minutes writing it. Don't make hime spend more than that in this chat :-)